# Angular Material Mat Horizontal Stepper not selecting the right step when advancing using a next button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat horizontal stepper i need to control using a Next and Back button, with steps generated using ngFor. I have created a variable "stepIndex" and binded it to the "selectedIndex" input, the Next button would increment this value and the Back would decrement it.

The completed steps should be marked with a check, this is done using the [completed] input of mat step which is true for any step with index smaller than the stepIndex, and the stepper should be linear to not allow selecting a future step.

Here is the link to the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guhqtk

I am encountering an issue with the next step which is incrementing the stepIndex correctly, but not displaying the step as being selected (selected step is in pink, completed steps in purple with a check), the selected step stays stuck at the first. I can select a previous step, or press back successfully, but when I try next again the step stays stuck.

For example, pressing next the first time does not change anything, while the expected behavior would be to have the second step selected and displaying in pink, pressing a second time shows the second step as complete as expected but the selected step should be the third step while it stays stuck on the first.

I am lost as to the origin of this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not use matStepperNext / matStepperPrevious?

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for the suggestion! I understood that this would need to be added inside the mat-step, so buttons for every step, while in my project the way it was already done is that we have just the these two buttons separate from the stepper. I will try to see if I can make it work using matStepperNext / matStepperPrevious but even if it works I would be curious to know why this solution is not working, it's frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the number of steps when pressing the next button and always increment the stepIndex

```
 onNextStep(){
    if(this.stepIndex < this.steps.length-1){
       ++this.stepIndex;
    }
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guhqtk-jazd1u

For the completed steps

```
[completed]="stepper.selectedIndex < stepper?.steps?.length"
```

note: it currently triggers a expression changed error

Comment: That's true thank you for pointing it out, but it does not relate to the problem I am facing

Comment: for example if you go now to the Stackblitz, I fixed the issue you mentioned, but when I press next until I reach step 6, this step is not selected but instead the step marked selected is stuck at the first step. The expected behavior would be that step 6 should show in pink. When i press back to reach step 5 again, step 5 is now correctly selected.

Comment: I added a stackblitz without the index because [completed]="i < stepIndex" is causing the troubles and it is much easier without it

Comment: Yes I tried this but problem is that i need it to disable the user from selecting the next step manually, the user should progress to the following step only using the Next button, and if he goes back he should not be able to go back to another future step

Comment: Yes I tried this but problem is that i need it to disable the user from selecting the next step manually, the user should progress to the following step only using the Next button, and if he goes back he should not be able to go back to another future step

Comment: Can you use the linear mode of the stepper?

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading between deploys :) I add a fix for the completed in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this still doesn't resolve my problem :(
I shouldn't be able to move forward by clicking on the stepper, to go forward I should only be able to click on Next (I can press on the previous steps in the stepper to go back, but I shouldn't be able to click in the next step in the stepper)